# og:image not scraping and not displaying

Tags: facebook

I've looked at the other questions posted on this topic as there was one specifically addressing the scraping but I was not able to see a solution there.

I would also like to know if the meta tags have to be on each web page or can they just be on one page?

My main issue is my image is not being scraped. I have used the debugger and searched and read and tried several things to fix this so the image is scraped and will show in any Facebook postings but have not had any success.  There is a lot of different info re the actual image size and I've tried various sizes but still no luck.  The site is [Soup Surreal](http://soupsurreal.com/Soup_Surreal/index.html)

Any suggestions or help is much appreciated. Thank you. Following is what was scraped.

```
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://soupsurreal.com/Soup_Surreal/index.html" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="Soup Surreal Serving, Stratford and Kitchener Region" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="I am delighted to introduce Soup Surreal products to you. With emphasis on quality and local ingredients, Soup Surreal products are made with passion and skill. It is my commitment to you to provide a quality and comforting soup to fill your bowl." />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Soup Surreal" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://soupsurreal.com/Soup_Surreal/images/fbimage.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1600" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:height" content="1957" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I get an error (403 Forbidden) when i try to access the image directly, that may explain why it is not displaying: http://soupsurreal.com/Soup_Surreal/images/fbimage.jpg

You should also check out this page for optimal image sizes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

...and yes, the OG tags should be on every page. At least on every page that should be shareable on Facebook (or elsewhere).

Comment: Hi Luschn and thank you.  Could this be something to do with the host site the owner of the website is using?  I've resized the image to be a bit smaller but well within the guidelines in the link you provided.

Comment: reducing the size is irrelevant, the aspect ration is much more important

Comment: ...and i still get that error. that´s the main reason why it does not work, it´s not accessible for facebook.

Comment: I contacted the company hosting the website about this issue and received the following reply:  "I found that images were blocked through .htaccess file. I have renamed ".htaccess" file to "hta" and the image in the link you have provided is working fine now."

I tried it and it is working - it gets scraped and now shows when I paste the URL in Facebook or in the address bar to check it directly.